# how save PDF file into database

Tags: java, android

i need to save PDF file into database from my android app.
Storing a PDF file or image is the same?
Online i didn't find any video tutorial that teach to store pdf file into database.

THANKS for the help in advance!

Comment: Bad practice. I suggest not to do that. It will cause performance issues.

Comment: `Storing a PDF file or image is the same?` Yes, they both come as a byte array. But do it if it's the only option, it's not a good practice to save files into a database.

Comment: @BackSlash i need to use base64 same?

Comment: @ZEUS, No. I mean, you can, but it's useless. And it's useless on images too, since you can directly save a byte array in the DB, without having to convert it to Base64. But again, this is a bad practice, the correct way would be to store it in the file system and save the file path on the DB.

Comment: @BackSlash now i save pdf into "archive" of android device, so i need to store the path into db? how can i do this?

Comment: @ZEUS It depends on how you save them. If you save them the way it's shown in the [android developers guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage) you can just save the file name, as the file base directory is provided by the context.

Comment: i don' know how store path of file into database :(

Comment: The path to a file is only a string. Do you know how to store a string in a table?

Comment: Then you need a crash course into Android + SQLite **CRUD**.

Answer (score 1):

Save the file to a directory related to your application and save its path into the database